# Can you change the integer value of a parameter at the end of a subroutine in python?

Tags: python, arrays, parameters, subroutine

for context a part of the code I am writing in python is that when a subroutine is run, it will add an integer, starting at 1, to an array by using append with an integer parameter that is equal to 1. at the end of the subroutine the parameter should be increased by one, so that next time the subroutine is run it will add 2 to the array. instead all that happens is it keeps adding the integer 1 to the array every time the code is run.

example code:

```
Number = int(1)

def Numberadd(Number):
    array.append(Number)
    Number += 1
```

if anyone knows why this is, or if its just straight up impossible, please let me know

Answer (score 0):

You can't because `Number += 1` creates a new variable inside the function. In the global namespace, `Number` will still be 1, while the function has a local variable `Number` set to `2`.

You can either make it global:

```py
Number = int(1)

def Numberadd(Number):
    global Number
    array.append(Number)
    Number += 1
```

Or make it into a list which can then be modified:

```py
Number = [int(1)]

def Numberadd(Number):
    array.append(Number)
    Number[0] += 1
```